# Google Forms Onclick Submit

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created a simple Google Form with two multiple choice answers (Yes and No). Image below.

The form works fine when I select an answer then click the submit button.

I'm wondering if it's possible to submit the form immediately when an option is selected? Then refresh the page.

I've been reading about triggers [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#ActionTriggers) but not sure where to start, or if it's even possible.

[image]

Google Forms is my only option at current, I know this is possible via other methods.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is an option for you, but if you use [toPrefilledUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#toPrefilledUrl()) to get your `yes` and `no` link it is possible. [I have done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852959/send-pre-filled-google-form-via-email/45046883#450468830) something similar to this for receiving responses to Google Forms from an email 
 type link

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if it's possible to submit the form immediately when an option is selected? Then refresh the page.

No, it's not possible. The only trigger that works on the form respondent view is on form submit.

The workaround is to create your own form. If you want to work with Google Apps Script, you should use the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/).

Comment: Isn't it possible to submit the form on option selected event if we use JS frameworks? (I know OP is not asking about any frameworks, I'm just curious)

Comment: @ParagJadhav That is a follow up question (: Please post it as a new question rather than as a comment.